# php mysql postcode check

Tags: php, mysql, forms

Hello I am only starting to learn php can anyone help.  I need to be able to check database for delivery postcode.

I have a table called delivery with two columns one is ID and other Postcode.

There will be several pre-recorded postcodes in database.  I have an input in a form for user to input postcode.  I need to check this postcode with database and if it exists continue if not show error.

Heres what I have so far.

```
<?php
include 'mysql_connect.php';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

        $postcodeQuery = sprintf("SELECT `Postcode` FROM delivery WHERE Postcode = '%s' LIMIT 1",
                    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['inputPostcode']));

        $postcodeResult = mysql_query($postcodeQuery);
        $delivery           = mysql_fetch_array($postcodeResult, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

        if ($_POST['inputPostcode'] == 'postcode')

        echo 'We deliver to your area'.($_POST['postcode']);

        } else{

        echo 'We do not deliver to your area';

}

?>
```

Please help kinda stuck!!

Comment: mysql_fetch_array second parameter should be MYSQL_ASSOC

Comment: You're using a MySQLi constant with the MySQL functions. The two libraries are not compatible with each other. Luckily the values of the constants are the same in both libraries, so this works, but only by chance.

Comment: removed the jquery and javascript-tags, as your post hast nothing to do with those.

Comment: Getting error Undefined offset: 0. onthis line if ($_POST['inputPostcode'] == $delivery[0]) Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
include 'mysql_connect.php';

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        echo 'Please enter an email address';

        $postcodeQuery = sprintf("SELECT `Postcode` FROM delivery WHERE Postcode = '%s' LIMIT 1",
                    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['inputPostcode']));

        $postcodeResult = mysql_query($postcodeQuery);
        $delivery       = mysql_fetch_array($postcodeResult, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

        if ($_POST['inputPostcode'] == $delivery[0])
            echo 'We deliver to your area '.($_POST['postcode']);
        else
            echo 'We do not deliver to your area';

}
```

This one should work - have a look at the manual page for [mysql_fetch_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) for the example.